# Storing data from Firestore to a list

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database storing a series of integer values that are entered daily by the user and stored as a list of integers. I have the following code that queries the data base and stores the searched for symptom value to a list that is then returned out of the function, while going through the for loop returnedData seems to contain all the values from the database however when I place `print(returnedData)` just after the query and before the return statement it prints an empty list. I'm not really sure why the for loop is not properly appending to the returnedData list.

```
func yearDataReturn(year: Int,symptom: String)->[Int]{
    //fetches all the year for the month and returns it as a list
    let collectionRef = db.collection("entries")
    var returnedData:[Int] = []
    collectionRef.whereField("year", isEqualTo: year).whereField("UserID", isEqualTo: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "UserID")).order(by: "monthOfYear").order(by: "weekOfMonth").order(by: "dayOfMonth")
        .getDocuments{(QuerySnapshot,err)in
            for doc in QuerySnapshot!.documents{
                let sympLis=doc.get("SymptomValues") as! [Int]

                let symp=sympLis[self.symptoms.firstIndex(of: symptom)!]
                returnedData.append(symp)
            }

    }
    return returnedData

}
```

Comment: Your function returns the array immediately after querying the database for the values. The call to `getDocuments` is asynchronous, which means that the thread you're currently on does not wait for the method to return before proceeding. You have to wait for `getDocuments` to return data before you can parse data and pass it out. That said, look into an escaping closure to handle this use case, not a standard returning function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly welcome to the site.

---

This is an async call which means the query line's (`collectionRef.whereField(...`) block will execute after the `return returnedData` line.

Please check this medium article -> [Managing async code in Swift](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f)

---

You can do this with pass a `closure` to your function like this ->

```swift
func yearDataReturn(year: Int,symptom: String, completion: @escaping ([Int] -> Void)) {
  //fetches all the year for the month and returns it as a list
  let collectionRef = db.collection("entries")
  var returnedData:[Int] = []

  collectionRef.whereField("year", isEqualTo: year).whereField("UserID", isEqualTo: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "UserID")).order(by: "monthOfYear").order(by: "weekOfMonth").order(by: "dayOfMonth")
    .getDocuments{(QuerySnapshot,err)in
      for doc in QuerySnapshot!.documents{
        let sympLis=doc.get("SymptomValues") as! [Int]

        let symp=sympLis[self.symptoms.firstIndex(of: symptom)!]
        returnedData.append(symp)
      }
      completion(returnedData)
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```swift
yearDataReturn(year: 5, symptom: "asdf") { symptomValues in
  print(symptomValues)
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the completion `@escaping` since the return value can escape the closure.

Comment: thanks for the reminding @bsod , please check my edited answer. And there is an article about `@escaping` and `@nonescaping` closures. I wanted to share the article because of others benefit -->> https://medium.com/@bestiosdevelope/what-do-mean-escaping-and-nonescaping-closures-in-swift-d404d721f39d